# C++ program to generate mnemonic seed, view/spend keys and wallet address?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, address, c++

Is there a simple C++ program to generate a mnemonic seed, view/spend keys and a wallet address? The reason I am asking this is because I am working on an iPhone product and I require this to integrate Monero in Swift and Xcode. If you have a better solution please let me know.

Comment: Can't you just use the official C++ monero repo?

Comment: I am not good at C++ so I am not certain which ones I should use.

Comment: src/wallet/wallet2.cpp, one of the generate functions.

Answer (score 2):

[*XMR*](https://github.com/skaht/XMR) is a bit clunky, but should get you rolling. Also look at http://moneroexamples.github.io/spendkey/.